# Consulta por intervalo de tempo no mongodb utilizando pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql

Preciso realizar uma consulta em um banco de dados mongodb que resulte um conjunto de resultados por faixa de tempo. Estou utilizando pymongo. A minha consulta está da seguinte forma:

```
queryConsulta = {"$and": [
                    {"id_no": id_node}, 
                    {"porta": porta},
                    {"datahora":{"$gte": self.horaInicio}},                      
                    {"datahora": {"$lte": self.now}}
                    ]}
listaResultados = db.minhacolecao.find(queryConsulta)
```

Eu também tentei dessa forma:

```
queryConsulta = {"id_no":int(id_node),
                    "porta":porta,
                    "datahora": {"$gte":self.horaInicio, "$lte":self.now }}
listaResultados = db.minhacolecao.find(queryConsulta)
```

Porém o resultado é sempre vazio. Testei diretamente no mongodb mas o resultado é vazio. Eu tenho certeza que os dados existem no banco de dados com a faixa de tempo que eu estou pesquisando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito vai depender de que tipo de dados são `datahora`, `self.horaInicio`e `self.now`.

Se `datahora` estiver salvo no MongoDB como `ISODate`, que é o mais comum, então você pode usar `datetime` em `self.horaInicio`e `self.now` e qualquer um de seus filtros devem funcionar.